# Convert Landsat image to polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat

I downloaded Landsat image and used composite band toolbox. Now, I produced color map but I need to create boundaries across urban area. Is there any way to create polygons among that area and how?

Answer (score 2):

The process you are describing is generally referred to as image classification.  ArcGIS has the capacity to do both unsupervised and supervised classification.  I would recommend reading [What is image classification](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00nv00000002000000) from ESRI help.  Once you complete the image classification, you can use a tool called [Raster to Polygon (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000008000000).

Additional Resources:

- [Image classification using the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00nv00000003000000)
- [An overview of the Image Classification toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00nv00000008000000)
- [Interactive Supervised Classification tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00nv0000000z000000)
- [Performing the classification](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000pw000000)

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer. Would image segmentation be applicable as an alternative to classification if the goal is simply to polygonize the image?

Comment: @WhiteboxDev I think image segmentation would be a great alternative.  Unfortunately, ArcGIS does not provide any image segmentation algorithms.  The OP could however use SPRING or QGIS to implement the image segmentation.